# Data model Type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ado.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Dispite the fact that the error msg is pretty obvious, I am not sure where I am making a mistake.

I used to use my entities with

```
using (gedaiappEntities context = new gedaiappEntities())
{

}
```

After I had renamed my project.. VS is not able to locate gedaiappEntities complaining that:

The type or namespace name `gedaiappEntities` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have deleted my ADO.NET Entity Data Model, re-created it with an item name `gedaiappModel`, my connection string previously set and with a model name as `gedaiappEntities`.

What I am supposed to do get my app working again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

I have not performed the right process to rename a project.

In the project properties tab, assembly name and Default namespace were set wrong.
After changed to the right names, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are the namespaces correct?  Try selecting the "gedaiappEntities" class that I'm assuming is red in your code since it can't find the reference.  Once it's selected, hit 'ctrl + .' (that's the ctrl and the period key) at the same time.  This should force Visual Studio to find the reference if you named the class correctly and will let you import it.